# Is it possible to prototype on window or window.location?

Tags: javascript

I want to write a query parsing method that would belong to the location class, but am not having any luck with

`window.location.prototype`

or

`window.prototype`

My goal is to do something along the lines of:

```
window.location.prototype.parseQuery = function(key){
   //run a test on this.search to see if it contains key and return the val
}
```

Is window immutable? or am I just not referencing it correctly?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the prototype when the object already exists and there's only one of them.  You can just add a method directly to the object.

```
window.parseQuery = function() { /* your code here */};
```

or

```
window.location.parseQuery = function() { /* your code here */};
```

Also, the `window` object is the global object in a browser so any global function is already a method on the `window` object.

Comment: so, in this case there's literally no difference between Window.prototype.parseQuery = ... and window.parseQuery = ..., huh?

Comment: I don't know about `Window.prototype`.  What I know is that the cross browser way to do what you're trying to accomplish is `window.parseQuery = function() {}`.  There is no reason to use a prototype here.

Answer (score 2):

You should add the property directly on `window.location`

```
window.location.parseQuery = function(key){
   //run a test on this.search to see if it contains key and return the val
}
```

`prototype` is the property of Function, while `window.location` is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

Bah! should have run some more tests before asking...

The answer is `Window.prototype`.  Works in Chrome, haven't tested elsewhere yet.

as per the answers given, it would seem that there's no need to prototype on Window, given that it's a single global object. So here's my solution...

```
window.location.getQueryItem = function(key){
            if(this.search.indexOf(key + "=") != -1){
                reg = new RegExp(key + '=(.*?)(\&|$)', 'i');
                return this.search.match(reg)[1];
            }
                    return null;
        }
```

Comment: As I said, it works in Chrome.  I haven't looked elsewhere yet, though the answers provided suggest that I won't have to, given the correct approach to this.

Comment: I have the method working with `Window.prototype` in Chrome v21 on OSX.

Comment: I see, if you type `Window` in console, it will give you `undefined`.